# Lightning Flash error with SemanticSegmentationData (NameError: name 'K' is not defined)

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I'm trying to perform an image segmentation task with Colab and [Lightning Flash](https://pypi.org/project/lightning-flash/).

I'm installing Flash with:

```
!pip install lightning-flash
```

I'm trying to instanciate a Lightning Flash SemanticSegmentationData using from_folders method like this:

```
datamodule = SemanticSegmentationData.from_folders(
    train_folder=x_train_dir,
    train_target_folder=y_train_dir,
    val_folder=x_valid_dir,
    val_target_folder=y_valid_dir,
    test_folder=x_test_dir,
    test_target_folder=y_test_dir,
    transform_kwargs=dict(image_size=(256, 256)),
    num_classes=1,
    batch_size=16,
)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flash/image/segmentation/input_transform.py in train_per_sample_transform(self)
 49             [DataKeys.INPUT, DataKeys.TARGET],
 50             KorniaParallelTransforms(
---> 51                 K.geometry.Resize(self.image_size, interpolation="nearest"), K.augmentation.RandomHorizontalFlip(p=0.5)
 52             ),
 53         )
NameError: name 'K' is not defined
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: well, why is it not defined? is it a library bug? then [submit a bug report to the authors](https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning-flash/issues). -- a complete traceback is required. you need to review [mre]

Comment: related bug: https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning-flash/issues/719 so you seem to be missing `kornia.augmentation`. please review [ask]. you should have done _some_ research before asking on SO.

Comment: I did some research. In theory the problem with kornia was solved in version 0.5, but I’m using the latest version 0.7.5 and I’m facing  an issue with kornia. That’s why I asked. I already opened a issue in their GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

Initially, I was trying to solve the problem this way:

```
!pip install kornia
import kornia as K
```

This didn't solve the problem. Then, I opened an issue in their GitHub [Issue #1423](https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning-flash/issues/1423). With a help from https://github.com/krshrimali, I discovered that just installing kornia would solve the problem.

So, the solution is just:

```
!pip install kornia
```